# QWebInspector Crash

Tags: qt

Every time I close the QWebInspector window my application crashes. I'm sure it's something simple, but I haven't been able to work it out.

I've isolated the problem to a very small test project here: https://github.com/axelstudios/QWebInspectorTest

Simply by right-clicking the webview, clicking "Inspect", and then closing the inspector dialog triggers the crash. The requirements are MSVC 2013, CMake 3, and Qt 5.x.

Also, I'm not able to reproduce this issue with the official webkitwidgets or webenginewidgets examples.